# How do you get the latest version number for a nuget package from the GitHub REST API?

Tags: github, nuget, nuget-package

How do you get the latest version number for a nuget package from the **GitHub** REST API?

I need this as part of my build script so I don't need to keep manually increment the version in my build file (PowerShell).

`curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -u myusername:<mykey> https://api.github.com/orgs/<mycompany>/packages/nuget/<mypackagename>`

I can't see the actual latest version number of the package in the response. I was expecting to see a JSON property with something like `latest_version: 1.0.24`

I can see that there is `version_count: 24`  but that doesn't help me build the full SEMVER version of 1.2.28 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Powershell helper function for this.

You will need to edit your Powershell profile to populate $env:GitHubAPIKey with your own GitHub Personal Access Token (or just change the variable name in the script if you already have this).

```
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66264349
write-output "Build helpers included"

<#
.SYNOPSIS
  This is a helper function that gets the next available NuGet package version from our NuGet package repository on GitHub
.EXAMPLE
  GetPackageVersion PackageName
#>
function GetNewPackageVersion
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=1)][string]$packageName
    )
    if (!$env:GitHubAPIKey) { 
        Write-Host "The environment variable `$env:GitHubAPIKey` is empty. Please ensure this is populated in your Powershell profile file at $home\Powershell\profile.ps1"  -BackgroundColor red -ForegroundColor Black
        exit -1
    }
    # TODO: If using PowerShell 7 rather than Windows Powershell 5.1, the next couple of lines can be improved by using the built in -authorization command
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "token",$env:GitHubAPIKey )))
    $results = Invoke-RestMethod  -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Uri   https://api.github.com/orgs/<your-organisation>/packages/nuget/$packageName/versions
    $v = [version]($results | Select-Object -first 1).name
    $newVersion = "$($v.Major).$($v.Minor).$($v.Build+1)"
    write-host ("New package version: " + $newVersion)  -BackgroundColor green -ForegroundColor Black
    return $newVersion
}
```

Usage:
."./BuildHelpers.ps1" # Include helper functions

```
$version = GetNewPackageVersion MyCompany.MyPackageName
echo $version
```

Output:

[image]